What is the simplest way to implement nearest neighbors vector search?
I have a Flask app which stores a (50k word) vocabulary of (300 dim'l) word embeddings in memory using a space-partitioning tree, and can quickly do a nearest neighbors search given a word embedding.
I'd like to move this app out of memory and into a DB. I've been using MySQL for other things, but I don't think it has good vector support. I'm using v8.0.39, and it sounds like v9.0 has support for VECTOR(N) but not nearest neighbors search.
Currently I have the word:embedding stored as string:string pairs. Doing 50k lookups would be really slow though at 1ms/lookup.
Is PostgreSQL + pgvector the best free/open-source solution for this? I'd have to migrate my databases from MySQL, which isn't a huge deal but it would be nice to avoid.

Hi, and welcomebto dba.se! For better or worse, product recommendations are considered off-topic here ("shopping-list"). Look here and do a bit of testing yourself - I've heard good things about pgvector! Postgresql extensions can be awesome!

@Vérace Thank you for the welcome! Okay, no worries. I think I'll try pgSQL + pgvector and see how it goes.
